# Undesirable Zero on the Output of Single Linked-list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, null, output

I am trying to do a simple linked-list in order to print the numbers inserted as arguments on the call of the program. However, it prints an undesirable zero on the final of the output. I guess it is a NULL that is printed, but I don't know how to get rid of it. I am still understanding the basics of linked-lists. Thank you.

```
/* */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>





/* */

#define NUMERO_DE_ARGUMENTOS_MINIMO             3
#define EOS                         '\0'





/* */

#define OK                          0
#define ARGUMENTO_NULO                      1
#define ARGUMENTO_VAZIO                     2
#define PONTEIRO_NULO                       3
#define NUMERO_DE_ARGUMENTOS_INVALIDO               101





/* */

typedef struct estruturaNumeros
{
  unsigned numero;
  struct estruturaNumeros *proximaEstrutura;
} tipoNumeros;





/* */

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  /* */

  tipoNumeros *numeroInicial, *proximoNumero;
  char *validacao;
  unsigned indiceArgumento;



  /* */

  numeroInicial = (tipoNumeros *) malloc(sizeof(tipoNumeros));



  /* */

  if (argc < NUMERO_DE_ARGUMENTOS_MINIMO)
  {
    printf("\n\n\nNumero de argumentos invalido.\n\n\n\n");
    exit(NUMERO_DE_ARGUMENTOS_INVALIDO);  /* Programa abortado. */
  } /* if */



  /* */

  if (!numeroInicial)
  {
    printf("\n\n\nPonteiro nulo.\n\n\n\n");
    exit(PONTEIRO_NULO);  /* Programa abortado. */
  } /* if */



  /* */

  proximoNumero = numeroInicial;



  /* */

  for (indiceArgumento = 1; indiceArgumento < argc; indiceArgumento++)
  {
    proximoNumero->numero = strtoul(*(argv + indiceArgumento), &validacao, 10);
    proximoNumero->proximaEstrutura = (tipoNumeros *) malloc(sizeof(tipoNumeros));
    proximoNumero = proximoNumero->proximaEstrutura;
  } /* for */



  /* */

  proximoNumero->proximaEstrutura = NULL;
  proximoNumero = numeroInicial;



  /* */

  printf("\n\n\n");



  /* */

  while (proximoNumero != NULL)
  {
    printf("%u\n", proximoNumero->numero);
    proximoNumero = proximoNumero->proximaEstrutura;
  } /* while */



  /* */

  printf("\n\n\n");



  return OK;  /* Codigo retornado com sucesso. */

} /* main */




/* output */

UBUNTU 05 --> ./exemplo_lista_encadeada_004 1 2 3



1
2
3
0
```

Answer (score 0):

The while test should be testing the structure pointer `proximaEstrutura`.

Your code uses a final (or terminal) node. It is the terminal node's proximaEstrutura member that is initialised to NULL.

```
  while (proximoNumero->proximaEstrutura != NULL)
    {
        printf("%u\n", proximoNumero->numero);
        proximoNumero = proximoNumero->proximaEstrutura;
    }
```